# R: Get workweek number, not seven day periods since Jan 1st

Tags: r, date, strptime, date-conversion, lubridate

Hi I am looking at data to do with prices of commodities throughout a period of a few years. I want to summarize prices by work weeks, not weeks defined by seven day periods since Jan 1st. When I tried:

```
data <- mutate(data, week = week(strptime(Date, "%m/%d/%Y")))
```

The lubridate week() function counts "1/13/10" (mdy) as week 2 and "1/14/10" as week 3. I want those to be in the same week. Basically any run of mon-fri in the same week. If the year starts on a wednesday I want week1 to be wed-fri, week2 to start the next monday. I have no data on any weekends. Any thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you week number assuming Date column is in Date format (you can use as.Date() to convert):

```
data <- mutate(data, week = format(Date, '%U'))
```

If you want week and year, you can use:

```
data <- mutate(data, week = format(Date, '%Y-%U'))
```

It will correctly number partial weeks.

Note: week number starts with 00 (but, that should be no problem).

You can also do it WITHOUT dplyr and it's mutate, like this:

```
data$week <- format(data$Date, '%U')
```

Comment: Your code is causing the error without `plyr`/`dplyr` packages loading.

Comment: Correct. It requires dplyr. But, since the question posted used mutate to begin with, I assumed dplyr solution was acceptable. I will edit to add a non-dplyr version as well.